# Unable to understand how to use fetch in this case?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I was solving a problem on a platform, but not getting how to do it?Can anyone help me out for this?
Problem Description

You are given the following API -

> GET /api/comments
>
> This will return a list of all comments. A comment object contains the following information
>
> userId - ID of the user who commented
>
> data - comment data
>
> Given a userId, return an Array of comment data of all the comments by the given user.
>
> Note
> Apart from .json(), don’t use any other methods on the response object returned from fetch() call. This can cause your tests to fail.
>
> Input - userId - the user id whose comment is to be returned.
>
> Output - A list of comments by the given user id
>
> Sample input 1 -
>
> userId = 1
>
> Sample API response
>
> ```
> comments = [
> {
>   'userId': '1',
>   "data": 'This looks slick!'
> },
> {
>   'userId': '2',
>   "data": 'I think this can be improved.'
> },
> {
>   'userId': '1',
>   "data": 'What kind of improvement?'
> }]
> ```
>
> Sample output 1 - ['This looks slick!', 'What kind of improvement?']

Below code that we have to complete

```js
// TODO - Implement getCommentsByUserId() function
async function getCommentsByUserId(userId) 
{
    let v=await fetch(`/api/comments/${userId}`,{})
    .then(response=>)

}

// ----------- Don't modify -----------
const mockFetch = (url, responseData) => {
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(responseData);
    const mockFetchPromise = (callUrl) => {
        if (url === callUrl) {
            return Promise.resolve({
                json: () => mockJsonPromise
             });
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('404: No such url')
        }
    }
    global.fetch = mockFetchPromise;
}

const successResponse = [
    {
        'userId': '1',
        "data": 'This looks slick!'
    },
    {
        'userId': '2',
        "data": 'I think this can be improved.'
    },
    {
        'userId': '1',
        "data": 'What kind of improvement?'
    }];
mockFetch('/api/comments', successResponse);

module.exports = getCommentsByUserId;
// ----------- Don't modify -----------

getCommentsByUserId("1").then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
let v = await fetch(`/api/comments/${userId}`,{})
.then(response=> response.json())
.then(comments => comments.filter(comment => comment.userId === userId))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but it is not passing any test cases , I don't know why, please read the question once again if possible

Comment: I think the problem is in your test code. For example, it should be `mockFetch('/api/comments/1', successResponse)` instead of `mockFetch('/api/comments', successResponse)`.

Comment: @Ankur see Quan To comments.

Comment: @QuanTo you are commenting on my answer not on his question comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking some knowledge on how `async/await` works. For filtering, as Alan has said, just use `Array.prototype.filter`.

When calling `fetch`, it returns a `Promise`. If you `await fetch(...)`, the code will wait till fetch is finished, and returns the response of that API call.

`async` functions always returns a `Promise` (unless called with await). However, when writing the `return` statement in `async` functions, you must return a normal value.

```js
async function getCommentsByUserId(userId) 
{
    let response = await fetch(`/api/comments/${userId}`,{});
    let comments = response.json();
    return comments.filter(comment => comment.userId === userId);
}
```

Either that, or using a normal function.

```js
function getCommentsByUserId(userId) 
{
    return fetch(`/api/comments/${userId}`,{})
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(comments => comments.filter(comment => comment.userId === userId));
}
```

Your test codes has many problems as well:

- `mockFetch('/api/comments', successResponse);`: Your test code is mocking calling for the url `"/api/comments/1"`, while you are mocking the API call for `"/api/comments"`
- `json: () => mockJsonPromise`: The `Response.json()` functions is expected to return an actual value, and not a promise.

Here is my fixed version.

```js
const mockFetch = (url, responseData) => {
    return (callUrl) => {
        if (url === callUrl) {
            return Promise.resolve({
                json: () => (responseData)
            });
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('404: No such url')
        }
    };
}

const successResponse = [
    {
        'userId': '1',
        "data": 'This looks slick!'
    },
    {
        'userId': '2',
        "data": 'I think this can be improved.'
    },
    {
        'userId': '1',
        "data": 'What kind of improvement?'
    }];

global.fetch = mockFetch('/api/comments/1', successResponse);

async function getCommentsByUserId(userId) {
    let response = await fetch(`/api/comments/${userId}`, {});
    let comments = response.json();
    return comments.filter(comment => comment.userId === userId);
}

getCommentsByUserId("1").then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but it is not passing any test cases , I don't know why, please read the question once again if possible

Comment: I added a fixed version of your test code

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes, now it's working fine but still, it doesn't clear any test cases.
However, it returns the same output as required.

```
    // TODO - Implement getCommentsByUserId() function
async function getCommentsByUserId(userId) {
    try{
    let response = await fetch(`/api/comments`, {});
    let comments = response.json();
    comments =  comments.filter(comment => comment.userId === userId);
    a=[]
    for(i of comments){
        a.push(i.data)
    }
    return a;
    }
    catch{
        return('404: No such url')
    }
}

// ----------- Don't modify -----------
const mockFetch = (url, responseData) => {
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(responseData);
    const mockFetchPromise = (callUrl) => {
        if (url === callUrl) {
            return Promise.resolve({
                json: () => (responseData)
             });
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('404: No such url')
        }
    }
    global.fetch = mockFetchPromise;
}

const successResponse = [
    {
        'userId': '1',
        "data": 'This looks slick!'
    },
    {
        'userId': '2',
        "data": 'I think this can be improved.'
    },
    {
        'userId': '1',
        "data": 'What kind of improvement?'
    }];
mockFetch('/api/comments', successResponse);

module.exports = getCommentsByUserId;
// ----------- Don't modify -----------

getCommentsByUserId("1").then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```